# Logical operator AND having higher order of precedence than IN

Tags: sql

I’ve read that logical operator AND has higher order of precedence than logical operator IN, but that doesn’t make sense since if that was true, then wouldn’t in the following statement the AND condition got evaluated before the IN condition ( thus before IN operator would be able to check whether Released field equals to any of the values specified within parentheses ?

```
SELECT Song, Released, Rating
FROM Songs
WHERE
Released IN (1967, 1977, 1987)
AND
SongName = ’WTTJ’
```

thanx

**EDIT:**

**Egrunin** and **ig0774**, I’ve checked it and unless I totally misunderstood your posts, it seems that

`WHERE x > 0 AND x < 10 OR special_case = 1`

is indeed the the same as

`WHERE (x > 0 AND x < 10) OR special_case = 1`

Namely, I did the the following three queries

```
SELECT * 
FROM Songs 
WHERE AvailableOnCD='N' AND Released > 2000 OR Released = 1989

SELECT *
FROM Songs
WHERE (AvailableOnCD='N' AND Released > 2000) OR Released = 1989

SELECT *
FROM Songs
WHERE AvailableOnCD='N' AND (Released > 2000 OR Released = 1989)
```

and as it turns out the following two queries produce the same result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Songs 
WHERE AvailableOnCD='N' AND Released > 2000 OR Released = 1989

SELECT *
FROM Songs
WHERE (AvailableOnCD='N' AND Released > 2000) OR Released = 1989
```

while

```
SELECT *
FROM Songs
WHERE AvailableOnCD='N' AND (Released > 2000 OR Released = 1989)
```

gives a different result

Comment: So, what result are you expecting? can you describe the results in simple terms? i.e get all songs released in 67, if it cant find it get the song with name 'WTTJ'.

Comment: He's expecting all songs that were (released in 1967, 1977, or 1987) AND (named 'WTTJ')

Comment: Your example is correct: be generous with parens.

Comment: Buy me a beer and all will be forgiven ;) Thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call me a n00b, but I **always** use parentheses in nontrivial compound conditions.

```
SELECT Song, Released, Rating
FROM Songs
WHERE
    (Released IN (1967, 1977, 1987))
AND
    SongName = ’WTTJ’
```

**Edited** *(Corrected, the point remains the same.)*

Just yesterday I got caught by this. Started with working code:

```
WHERE x < 0 or x > 10
```

Changed it in haste:

```
WHERE x < 0 or x > 10 AND special_case = 1
```

Broke, because this is what I wanted:

```
WHERE (x < 0 or x > 10) AND special_case = 1
```

But this is what I got:

```
WHERE x < 0 or (x > 10 AND special_case = 1)
```

Comment: Uhm, are you implying that “WHERE x > 0 AND x < 10 OR special_case = 1” is the same as “WHERE x > 0 AND (x < 10 OR special_case = 1)”? I thought that “WHERE x > 0 AND x < 10 OR special_case = 1” is the same as “WHERE (x > 0 AND x < 10) OR special_case = 1”?!

Comment: @AspOnMyNet: Nope. AND is evaluated first, so x < 10 OR special_case = 1 is understood as the right-hand side of the evaluation.

Comment: @AspOnMyNet: you just proved my point. A couple of extra parens is better than too few.

Comment: @AspOnMyNet - fixed my example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you're using SQL Server, as in SQL Server [`AND` has a higher order of precedence than `IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx). So, yes, the AND is evaluated first, but [the rule for evaluating `AND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188372.aspx), is to check the [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx) on the left (in your sample, the `IN` part) and, if that is true, the expression on the right. In short, the `AND` clause is evaluated first, but the `IN` clause is evaluated as part of the `AND` evaluation.

It may be simpler to understand the order of precedence here as referring to how the statement is parsed, rather than how it is executed (even if MS's documentation equivocates on this).

---

*Edit in response to comment from the OP:*

I'm not all together certain that `IN` being classified as a logical operator is **not** specific to [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL). I've never read the ISO standard, but I would note that the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) and [Oracle](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67779/operator.htm) docs define `IN` as a comparison operator, [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-subquery.html) as a subquery expression, and [Sybase itself](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/6070;pt=6070#X) as a "list operator". In my view, Sybase is the nearest to the mark here since the expression `a IN (...)` asks whether the value of attribute `a` is an element of the list of items between the parentheses.

That said, I might imagine the reason that SQL Server chose to classify `IN` as a logical operator is two-fold:

1. `IN` and the like do not have [the type restrictions of the SQL Server comparison operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) (`=`, `!=`, etc. cannot apply to text, ntext or image types; `IN` and other subset operators can be used against any type, except, in strict ISO SQL, `NULL`)
2. The result of an `IN`, etc. operation is a boolean value just like the other "logical operators"

Again, to my mind, this is not a sensible classification, but it is what Microsoft chose. Maybe someone else has further insight into why they may have so decided?

Comment: Yes, I’m using sql server, though the book is on Sql in general. A) Operators ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, SOME also have lower precedence than AND. I assume they too are treated like IN operator in that they are evaluated as part of an expression on the left or right of the AND operator  ( and as part of an AND evaluation )


B) But why then is IN considered logical operator and not comparison operator?

Comment: “=, !=, etc. cannot apply to text, ntext” What do you mean by saying that operators " =, != etc. " can’t be applied to text? Aren’t we allowed to have comparisons like Some_column = 'A' ?

Comment: @AspOnMyNet 'text', 'ntext', etc. is an outmoded TSQL datatype. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx. Most columns that store textual data are of type VARCHAR (variable-length character) or CHAR (fixed-length character). In older versions of SQL Server there were hard limits to how long a VARCHAR field could be which TEXT allowed to be exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql at least, it has a lower precedence.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 2):

I think of `IN` is a comparison operator whereas `AND` is a logical operator.  So it's a bit apples and oranges, since the comparison operator must be evaluated first to see if the condition is true, then the logical operator is used to evaluate the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is never ambiguity about how `IN` works in terms of precedence with logical operators.

`IN` needs an expression to its left side. This is not only different to a condition, but (t)sql is one of the few languages I've seen that will *not* automatically convert an expression to a condition implicitly by using 0/1.

If you run: `select case when 5=5 in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end` you will receive an incorrect syntax error. It's not like 5=5 will return 1, like some other languages do.

On the other hand, logical operators need conditions to their sides. And conditions have also no implicit way from tsql to get converted into expressions - only the `case` statement does that. Running: `select * from yourtable where column1` again yields an error.

So if you see
`(logical operator) (something) IN (....)`
then either:

1. (something) is an expression, which is something `IN` needs, but not a logical operator needs not. The `IN` gets evaluated (despite supposedly having lower precedence!), and it returns a "boolean" (ie, the result of a condition), and that CAN get used by the logical operator

- or -

2. (something) is a condition, which can be used by the logical operator. But, all logical operators return "boolean", so really this scenario is always a syntax error.

Things are easier on the right side: I know of no operators that use a list of values `(1,2,3)` or even `(select col from sometable)` other than `IN`.

You can argue that there is ambiguity if the expression on the left side can also be used by an operator that uses expressions, like say addition. In this case, yeah, the precedence is useful and tell us this thing will happen first. So, this:

`select case when 5*3 in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end`

returns 0 because the multiplication happens first.